# React select menu list was shaking when scrolling down on safari

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-select

I'm using select field from [react-select](https://react-select.com).

When I scroll the mouse down to the last item in the select field, the menu dropdown shakes a bit. It was ok when using Google Chrome, it only occurred when using Safari. Is there any way to handle this issue?

Here're my code: [demo-code-react-select-bug](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-menu-list-shaking-when-scroll-2ll3xw?file=/src/App.tsx)